# Best way to implement/call a class that returns an immutable value?

Tags: python

I would something like this in Python:

```
result = SomeClass(some_argument)
```

Here is the catch though. I don't want the result to be an instance but an immutable object (int, for example). Basically the hole role of a class is returning a value calculated from the argument. I am using a class and not a function for DRY purposes.
Since the above code won't work because it will always return an instance of SomeClass what would be the best alternative?

My only idea is to have a static method, but I don't like it:

```
result = SomeClass.static_method(some_argument)
```

Comment: In what way does using a class instead of a function serve DRY purposes?

Comment: `def SomeClass(arg): return arg*42`?

Comment: I had a lot of Django function views having some repeating blocks of code or code structures. So I created an abstract class to take care of the boiler plate and inherited that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `__new__`.  **This is rarely a good idea and/or necessary** though ...

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __new__(cls):
...         return 1
... 
>>> Foo()
1
>>> type(Foo())
<type 'int'>
```

If you don't return an instance of `cls`, `__init__` will never be called.

Comment: That is what I was looking for :). Why isn't it a good idea, though?

Comment: It's just very unexpected behavior.

Comment: I see. You are right. For a user of the class it can be confusing. But when you have something like discount = calculate_discount(price) it's perfect. The user shouldn't care that it's actually a class.

Comment: @AlBundy -- Sure, but why make it a class in the first place?  Why not use a function?

Comment: Because I would have a lot of functions that would look the same. It's a case of repeating not blocks of code but the code structure. When this becomes big it's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically class methods are the way to go if you have a factory method.
About the result - it really depends on what kind of immutability you seek, but basically namedtuple does a great job for encapsulating things and is also immutable (like normal tuples):

```
from collections import namedtuple
class FactoryClass(object):
     _result_type = namedtuple('ProductClass', ['prod', 'sum'])
     @classmethod
     def make_object(cls, arg1, arg2):
         return cls._result_type(prod=arg1 * arg2, sum=arg1 + arg2)

>>> FactoryClass.make_object(2,3)
ProductClass(prod=6, sum=5)
>>> x = _
>>> x.prod = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```